# Script to write logs in to file

Tags: bash, scripting, ping

I was trying to write script witch will ping some address, for example `Google.com`, and when connection is lost, write the log in to file. I don't know how to do it. 
Example:

```
ping goodle.com
```

if connected just ping

if not connected write log into file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ! ping -c2 google.com >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    printf '%s\tgoogle.com not reachable\n' "$(date)" >>logfile
fi
```

This makes `ping` try to ping Google twice. If it fails (`ping` returns a non-zero exit status), a message is added to a logfile.

Comment: Hmm, in your script i get always `google not rechable` eaven when i have Internet connection.

Comment: @SanHolo That's because I missed negating the test. Sorry.

Comment: So how it should looks?

Comment: @SanHolo As it does now. I fixed it as soon as I saw your comment.

Comment: Maybe i ask in wrong way but I would like to google it was ping all the time, unless it will not be possible to connect to google and then the information will be saved to a file. Now your script work fine, but i need to ping 24/7 to chec my connection. Can you show me how?

Comment: I remove `-c2` and it works. Thanks :)

Comment: @SanHolo May I ask what Unix you are on?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 3):

In its simplest form, you could do something like this:

```
ping -c2 google.com 2>&1 >/dev/null || echo "$(date) host not available" >> /tmp/mylogfile
```

`ping` will return success (exit code 0) if it can ping, and a non-zero code otherwise, so only in the second case will the echo be executed. (`-c2` means just ping twice, usually, `ping` will try and try again until you stop it.)

Comment: The order of the redirections from `ping` should be reversed.

Comment: this script works perfectly. And great description of working your script. Thanks.